# easiest way to generate files in jni folder android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, javah

I am wondered if there is a way to generate the .h files in the jni folder easier than command like this

```
javah -jni -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.example.test_ndk.FibLib
```

I mean I want to automate this step so I have to write only

```
public native static long fibNR(long n);
```

and then eclipse will generate the .h files in jni folder for me

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1:**

If it makes a difference, you do not have to include the `-jni` option. It's the default option for `javah`.

```
javah -classpath bin/classes/ -d jni/ com.example.test_ndk.FibLib
```

**Option 2:**

The other alternative would be to create the header file yourself, but this is not an easier option. Your header would look like this (there's a 1 before `ndk` in `test_1ndk` because you used an `_` character in the package name. If we don't put it, the caller will look for a folder called `ndk` inside a folder called `test`, therefore, I wouldn't recommend using test_ndk as your package name. Instead use testNdk or something with the underscore):

```
#include <jni.h>
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_test_1ndk_FibLib(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong);
// use jobject instead of jclass if your method is non-static
```

And the general format is:

```
JNIEXPORT [returnType] JNICALL Java_[package name with folders separated by _]_[class name]_[method name] (JNIEnv*, jclass, jtype arguments);
```